# Change Button Style When Stock is Over Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to do a hook to change the style of the buy button when the product is without stock.
I have done something like this, but without success.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock', $product ); 
function action_woocommerce_no_stock( $product ) { ?>
    <style>
        .btn-assine {
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock', 'action_woocommerce_no_stock');
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually Woocommerce removes the button if the product is out-of-stock. If your product settings is allowing backorders then you'll see the button and probably the CSS class for this button will be different from the others.

Comment: I'm using a custom button to this order and using subscriptions. When this product is out of stock, this button redirects to home, but the style doesnt change

Comment: please send us the link for the product that is out of stock

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Below Code.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock', $product ); 
function action_woocommerce_no_stock( $product ) { 
 echo '
  <style type="text/css">
    .single-product .product .single_add_to_cart_button.button{
         background-color: #333333;
         color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .woocommerce .product .add_to_cart_button.button{
         background-color: #333333;
         color: #FFFFFF;
    }
 </style>
';
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock', 'action_woocommerce_no_stock', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: I'm using a custom button to this order and using subscriptions. I try this code, but the style doesnt change